# extraHeaders not being attached to petition

Tags: node.js, angular, sockets, typescript, socket.io

I'm trying to integrate socket.io with my angular that. For that, I've followed the steps outlined in [this](https://blog.codewithdan.com/2017/11/07/pushing-real-time-data-to-an-angular-service-using-web-sockets/) article. Since my server (which uses Express) is using jwt based authentication, I'm setting the authentication headers as per the socket.io [docs](https://socket.io/docs/client-api/#with-extraheaders). Here's the Angular service code:

```
@Injectable()
export class PushNotificationsService {

  socket: SocketIoModel;
  observer: Observer<any>;
  environment;

  constructor (private authService: AuthService) {
    this.environment = environment; // This contains the server endpoints 
  }

  async getQuotes (): Promise<Observable<number>> {
    this.socket = socketIo(this.environment.url, {
      transportOptions: {
        transports: ['polling'],
        polling: {
          extraHeaders: {
            'Authorization': `Bearer ${await this.authService.getToken()}`
          }
        }
      }
    });

    this.socket.on('data', (res) => {
      this.observer.next(res.data);
    });

    return this.createObservable();
  }

  createObservable (): Observable<number> {
    return new Observable(observer => {
      this.observer = observer;
    });
  }

  private handleError (error) {
    console.error('server error:', error);
    if (error.error instanceof Error) {
      const errMessage = error.error.message;
      return Observable.throw(errMessage);
    }
    return Observable.throw(error || 'Socket.io server error');
  }    
}
```

If I inspect the `socket` attribute, I can see that the option is being set. But, when I inspect my app's petitions with the browser, I can see that the `Authentication` header is not present:
[image]

Any ideas on what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Transports option goes at the same level as TransportOptions.

You could try if that makes a difference but I don't think that is your problem though as "polling" is the default anyway.